# How to import an existing RSA key into YubiHSM?

Tags: yubico, yubikey

I know how to do it in Yubikey, but I have a YubiHSM2. Don't know how to do it.

The following is for Yubikey, not for YubiHSM

```sh
$ yubico-piv-tool -a import-key -s 9c -i root.key
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it. Use yubihsm-shell

```sh
yubihsm> put asymmetric 0 0 mykey 1 sign-pkcs rsa.pem
```